# Why does new custom event log returned by EventLog.GetEventLogs contain Application log entries?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, powershell, event-viewer

I have a very strange issue that doesn't seem to correspond to any of the documentation I'm reading about EventLog.GetEventLogs.

I created a new custom log using Powershell (a very straightforward operation) which contains zero entries. However, when I call EventLog.GetEventLogs and locate the new log in the resulting array, the Entries property contains *all of the Application log entries.* I was expecting the number of entries to be zero, which is what I see in the event viewer.

What could cause this result?

PowerConsole:

```
> New-EventLog
> Log Name? MyModule
> Souce Name 1? MyModule
> Source Name 2?
```

C# Code:

```
var logs = EventLog.GetEventLogs();
var log = logs.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Log == "MyModule");

Response.Write(log.Entries.Count); // Outputs 18,896
```

Comment: Hi, you need to show the code that you're using.

Comment: There's really nothing to it. I'm calling GetEventLogs with no arguments and looping through the results looking for an event log with the matching name. The fist result is the Application log, which contains 18896 entries, and the second result is the brand new custom log, which also contains 18896 entries.

Comment: The documentation for this method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.geteventlogs?view=netframework-4.7.2), if that is what you are in fact calling, states: _ 
Searches for all event logs on the local computer and creates an array of EventLog objects that contain the list._.  It appears that this will **not** filter to a specific custom log.

Comment: By "all event logs" it's referring to collections of entries. There are other logs returned by that same method call that have zero entries. I'm working on adding some code and the PowerConsole command I used.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking at the wrong method.

Rather than calling `GetEventLogs`, get a reference to your custom log, and **then** look at it's entries:

```
EventLog myLog = new EventLog("my_log");           
var count = myLog.Entries.Count;
```

If we then write an entry like this:

```
EventLog myLog = new EventLog("my_log");
myLog.Source = "my_source";
myLog.WriteEntry("A test entry");
```

The count will increase as expected.

Comment: I just updated the question with some code. I think your approach would be better, because then I'm not retrieving all of the logs I don't care about, but I'm not sure that this is the reason for issue I'm experiencing.

Comment: I've just run this code locally, creating a test log as per your powershell process.  First call returns 0, and writing a log entry via `log.WriteEntry()` increments this count by 1, as expected.

Comment: Good to know. I'll try again tomorrow. I did play with the registry to create a new log source with the same name prior to using that power shell command. I deleted the new registry key before moving on, but maybe it had side effects.

Comment: I used Remove-EventLog to remove the log and then called New-EventLog, this time passing the log name and source name as arguments. Now I get the expected results.

Comment: My celebration was premature. Although it initially returned zero entries, now it's returning five entries. It appears that the Application log was cleared, and now only has five entries. So the only reason my new log had 0 entries was because the Application log was wiped out.

Comment: Restarting my computer resolved the issue. I'm assuming there's probably some command I could have run to apply the registry changes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The PowerShell command that creates new logs ultimately modifies the registry. I'm guessing that some of those registry settings don't get applied until some other command is executed. After restarting my machine, EventLog.GetEvenLogs produced the expected results.